# Deleting data from a queue

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I need help using a queue in C++.

I have a `struct` which contain 2 members that I want to delete later:

```
#define MAX 10

struct queue{
    int head,tail;
    string code[max], title[max];
} q;
```

And here's my dequeue code:

```
void delete(){
    if(empty()){
        cout<<"Queue is empty!";
    }else{ 
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < q.tail; i++)
            q.code[i]=q.code[1+i];
        q.title[i]=q.title[i+1];
        q.tail--;
    }
    show_data();
}
```

Let's say that I have input 3 items into the queue:

1. if01 | c++
2. if02 | ruby
3. if03 | java

I want to delete items one by one. Because its a queue, the first data that should be deleted is number 1, right?

So it should end up like this:

1. if02 | ruby
2. if03 | java

But unfortunately, it doesn't work like that, the output that I get is:

1. if02 | c++
2. if03 | ruby

And then if I try to delete again, i get output like this:

1. if03 | c++

I don't know why the `title` won't be deleted like the `code`.

If I try to reverse the loop, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < q.tail; i++)
    q.title[i]=q.title[i+1];
q.code[i]=q.code[1+i];
q.tail--;
```

The `code` won't delete, but the `title` deletes normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not moving around both `code` and `title` members together.  You are moving around only one of them inside the loop, and then you move the other one around *1 time* AFTER the loop is finished.

You need to some add additional braces to your loop body, eg:

```
void delete() {
    if (empty()) {
        cout << "Queue is empty!";
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < q.tail; ++i) { // <-- add brace
            q.code[i]  = q.code[1+i];
            q.title[i] = q.title[i+1]; // <-- do this INSIDE the loop!
        } // <-- add brace
        q.tail--;
    }
    show_data();
}
```

I would suggest an alternative implementation - move the `code` and `title` members to their own `struct` that is separate from the `queue`, and then you can move instances of that `struct` around as a single unit, eg:

```
const int maxItems = 10;

struct data {
    string code, title;
};

struct queue {
    int head, tail;
    data items[maxItems];
} q;

...

void delete() {
    if (empty()) {
        cout << "Queue is empty!";
    }
    else { 
        for (int i = 0; i < q.tail; ++i)
            q.items[i] = q.items[1+i];
        q.tail--;
    }
    show_data();
}
```

Comment: good evening , thank you so much for the answer ! it helps alot.

Comment: also thank you for the tip , it gives me more knowledge !